# formula values are not getting in URL in Production

Tags: javascript, custom-button, formula-field

I created a custom button on custom object.

Behavior= "Execute Javascript"

Content Source="Onclick Javascript"

I have written the following code in sandbox. It is working in Sandbox.  But,  In Production, Formula values are not coming.

```
          if({!productForce__c.Channel_code__c<>'Z0'&&productForce__c.Channel_code__c<>'Z4'}) {
   alert('{!$Label.Alert_for_projected_stock}');
   } else {

   window.open("https://{!productForce__c.SAP_Environment__c}.corp.inpkg.net:{!productForce__c.PORT_for_SAP_URL__c}/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/zbu_apo_projected_stock?sap-language={!productForce__c.Language_Code__c}&company= 
{!productForce__c.Country_Name__c}&BASEPRODUCT= 
{!productForce__c.PBcode__c}&OK_CODE=EXECUTE#");
   }
```

sanbox URL when we click on button: 
https://scmdev.corp.inpkg.net:8400/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/zbu_apo_projected_stock?sap-language=FR&company=FRANCE&BASEPRODUCT=8022735&OK_CODE=EXECUTE#

Production URL when we click on button: 
https://corp.inpkg.net/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/zbu_apo_projected_stock?sap-language=&company=&BASEPRODUCT=8006451&OK_CODE=EXECUTE#

Comment: please check those fields are present in production you used in javascript. If both of them are not not in sink.There may be probability to get the error.cross verify it once

Comment: Check their permission as well.

Comment: I have found  in community, Salesforce eliminate the use of JavaScript in hyperlink formula fields. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MQknQAG

Answer (score 0):

Only execution of Javascript in the **hyperlink** has been eliminated by salesforce in summer 17 release. 
I think in this case the issue might be because of fields are not available in prod. or else might be issue with the field permissions.

Comment: The Field Accessibility is "hidden" in Production. But while deploying from sandbox the Field Accessibility  is "Read-Only" in Sandbox.